# Apache wont work after changing port

Tags: server, apache2, hosting

I am working with Ubuntu 12.04 server 64-bit edition. I have installed apache2 without any problems and i can see the "It works" message. And I can also access from other pc within the network.

I want to host my website using home DSL, However I found out that my ISP is blocking ports 80, 25 and 110 so I changed the port to 8010 (in `/etc/apache2/port.conf`)

After this I am unable to get the "It Works" web page. All it shows that "NOT FOUND". I tried with `ipaddress:8010` and it doesn't work with either internal or external.

Comment: whats the output of sudo netstat -ntlp

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your VirtualHost setting, too

Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

Change

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
```

to

```
 <VirtualHost *:8010>
```

And make sure that your `ports.conf` looks like

```
 NameVirtualHost *:8010
 Listen 8010
```

And don't forget to restart apache

Comment: when i type the address for ex: www.xyz.com the browser changes it to my ip address... does that because i have not set up DNS yet?


Also i heard when you change the apache port no  DNS (BIND9) doesnot work. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you changed the port correctly. It is quite easy. You need to make a few changes to `httpd.conf` file as follows:

Change:

`Listen 80` to `Listen 8080`
and

`ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName localhost:8080`